# Spring Security Customizing Authorization Endpoint URL

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am implementing a Spring MVC REST web service and attempting to security it with Spring Security Oauth2.

My authorization URL is at the following address (note that there is no registration id):

```
http://localhost:8080/myoauthserver/oauthservlet
```

So, in my Spring Security Config, I have this:

```java
    @Bean
    @Profile("dev")
    public ClientRegistration devClientRegistration() {
                
        // set up variables to pass to ClientRegistration

        ClientRegistration result = ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId("") // this obviously doesn't work
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationUri(authorizationUri)
                .tokenUri(clientSecret)
                .userInfoUri(userInfoUri)
                .userNameAttributeName(userNameAttribute)
                .redirectUri(redirectUrl)
                .providerConfigurationMetadata(providerDetails)
                .build();
        
        return result;
    }
    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        
        ClientRegistrationRepository repository = new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(devClientRegistration());
        
        return repository;
    }
    @Bean
    @Profile("dev")
    public SecurityFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        // this prevents throwing an exception in the oauth2 lambda function
        Map<String, String> loginProps = ...
        
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                // what we want is for a few urls to be accessible to all, but most to require
                // oauth authentication/authorization
                .antMatchers("/login/**","/error/**", "/oauth2/**").anonymous()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> {
                oauth2
                    .clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrationRepository(loginPropsCopy))
                    .authorizationEndpoint()
                        .baseUri("http://localhost:8080/myoauthserver/oauthservlet");
            }
            );


        return http.build();
    }
```

How do I customize the entire authorization endpoint to not try to tack the registration id onto it?

Comment: Why not do `ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(...).authorizationUri(authorizationUriWithNoRegistrationId)`? It seems like this would work. Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @jzheaux it doesn't work. Basically, no matter what I try, it still appends ```/registrationId``` (or whatever the registration id is) to the end of the URL.

Comment: I wonder if there are two different things going on. There is the "authorization request" endpoint, which is the endpoint in Spring Security to send a request to the authorization server to start the authorization code grant flow. Then, there is the "authorization response" endpoint, which is the endpoint in Spring Security to process the authorization code grant returned from the authorization server. The above configuration conflates the two bc it sets the authorizationUri on the registration ("authorization response") and it sets the same URI on the DSL ("authorization request").

Comment: Can you please update your question to clarify which are you wanting to remove the registrationId from?